# Method not returning expected value

Tags: c#, methods, return

I have no idea what is wrong with the code below. my returns are not working.
I have commented in the code some more details.

item is a line in a text file. An example being "`Port; 2302;`"

```
    portTextBox.Text = Config_check(item, "Port", 1);
    private string Config_check(string item, string contains, int i)
    {
        string part = "defualt";
        if (item.Contains(contains))
        {
            MatchCollection Parts = Regex.Matches(item, @"(?i); *(.+?);(?-i)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
            foreach (Match m in Parts)
            {
                part = m.Groups[i].Value; // sets part to '2302'
                MessageBox.Show(part); // Shows '2302', Does open message box
                return part; // Dosnt work
            }
            MessageBox.Show(part); // Shows 'Defualt' why?!?!
            return part; // Dosnt work
        }
        MessageBox.Show(part); // Shows 'Defualt' why?!?!
        return part; // returns 'Defualt'
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged through? It is possible that your input and regular expression are not doing and are different from what you expect.

Comment: That is, your comments about what is happening suggest that the regular expression doesn't match the `item`.

Comment: What is the value of "item" and why do you expect the regular expression to match it?

Comment: Item is a line in a text document, for an example in that text document it says `Port; 2302;`
if the line contains Port search for anything between the two ; 
The message box in the foreach shows up with the correct value so i know that bit works. Its the return that dosnt work.

Comment: Well, both the second and third `return`s give you "defualt" because `part` is never set to anything else.

Comment: @Sty how would i go about fixing this then?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? If Regex doesn't find a match then the foreach doesn't get executed and it shows "defualt". Same if .Contains() fails. And a return inside a foreach-loop ends the function

Comment: @Jason1232 I suggest starting [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return). When you `return`, your method exits. I would also suggest taking a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as you don't really explain in your question what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: My understanding of c# is very limted but from what i have been told the return is ment to exit the method and well, return the value it had next to it. It dosn't seem to be doing that.

Comment: @Melissa But i know the foreach loop is getting executed as the messagebox within the foreach loop shows the correct value (2302)

Comment: You need to provide sample values for the 3 arguments 'item', 'contains' and 'i'. I don't know your function inputs/arguments so I don't know what code is executed.

Comment: Another mistake I see is that you start indexing Groups[] with 1 and not 0. But the code above cannot work as a function declaration and an assignment are on the same code "level". There is some code missing and may it just code to refresh the control text to show the returned value.

Comment: @Melissa, contains and i are both in the question. item is a line in a text file an example would be "`Port; 2302`"

Comment: @Melissa that is not a mistake. Groups[0] returns the entire line (i do not need the entire line) Groups[1] outputs what i need (2302)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that now. I'm not really sure what the actual purpose of the regular expression is because it looks incorrect or incomplete and therefore fails (or returns no matches).

Comment: @Melissa the Regex works fine and does get matches

Comment: What are you expecting to match when you use `(?i)` in a regular expression? Same for `(?-i)`... I bet it's not what you expect. Both expressions do no meaningful operation. You created a named group `i` that matches the empty string for the first. Then you have a balancing group balancing the `i` group with nothing. Both parts of the regular expression succeeds matching on nothing. Ultimately, it seems your question boils down to... "why doesn't my regular expression work?"

Comment: Yes, and it works for " Porto Grande; 2302; 7656 and more text here" as well. And your message box confirms you extract the number-string "2302" as written by you above. Your error lies somewhere else in code you didn't post.

Comment: yes part is being set to 2302 my issue is i cant output it from that method. The textbox is getting set to "Defualt"

Also the only place i have any refrence to defualt is in that method

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is the return statement inside the loop. If you return from your method, the rest of your method won't be executed anymore. So probably all you have to do is to remove the inner returns:

```
portTextBox.Text = Config_check(item, "Port", 1);
private string Config_check(string item, string contains, int i)
{
    string part = "defualt";
    if (item.Contains(contains))
    {
        MatchCollection Parts = Regex.Matches(item, @"(?i); *(.+?);(?-i)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        foreach (Match m in Parts)
        {
            part = m.Groups[i].Value;
            MessageBox.Show(part);
        }
        MessageBox.Show(part);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(part);
    return part;
}
```

However, as I don't know the rest of your code, it might still not work.

This actually doesn't seem as a very good attempt anyway, as you're overwriting `part` inside your foreach loop, so that the only value, which will be in `part`, will be the one that was saved in the last match from `Parts`.

---

**EDIT**

If you don't want the foreach loop, you could simply take the last item:

```
portTextBox.Text = Config_check(item, "Port", 1);
private string Config_check(string item, string contains, int i)
{
    string part = "defualt";
    if (item.Contains(contains))
    {
        MatchCollection Parts = Regex.Matches(item, @"(?i); *(.+?);(?-i)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
        part = Parts.OfType<Match>().LastOrDefault() ?? "default";
        MessageBox.Show(part);
    }
    MessageBox.Show(part);
    return part;
}
```

You can (obviously) remove the message box inside the foreach loop.

Comment: is there a way i could just get rid of the foreach loop? i dont need it i only want Groups[1] anyway

Comment: You can remove the MessageBox.Show(part) statement inside the if statement.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg As it probably existed just for debugging reasons, I won't remove it.

Comment: Well, actually not. The original code left after showing a messagebox. But in this case (if item contains) you'll see the same message twice.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I mentioned it in my answer.